# CakePHP find count of records from associated Models

Tags: php, cakephp, one-to-many

I have a `Job` model and a `Visit` model, a Job can have many Visit's. I have set up the relationships appropriately in my Models.

A Visit also belongs to a `Supplier`, so a `Supplier` can have many visits.

A subcontractor is a Supplier who has an `engineer` value of 0 in the database.

I want to return an associative array with the amount of Jobs raised per subcontractor, something like this:

```
$supplier_job_count = array(
    'Subcontractor1' => 23,
    'Subcontractor2' => 3,
    'Subcontractor3' => 7,
    'Subcontractor4'=> 0
);
```

Here is what I have:

```
    $conditions = array();   

    // get all the visits in the database 
    $visits = $this->Job->Visit->find('all');

    // extract all the visit id's
    $visit_supplier_ids = Hash::extract($visits, '{n}.Visit.supplier_id'); // 11612 records        

    // get all the subcontractors in the database
    $subcontractors = $this->Job->Visit->Supplier->find('all', array('order' => 'id ASC', 'conditions' => array('Supplier.engineer' => 0)));

   // extract all the subcontractor id's
   $subcontractor_ids = Hash::extract($subcontractors, '{n}.Supplier.id'); // 1288 records

   // intersect arrays so we only want matching values from both, i.e. only want visits whose supplier is a subcontractor
    $visit_subcontractors = array_values(array_intersect($visit_supplier_ids, $subcontractor_ids));

    // find all visits who is a subcontractor id
    $visits = $this->Job->Visit->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Visit.supplier_id' => $visit_subcontractors)));

    // extract out the job id's for the subcontractor visits
    $visit_jobs_ids = Hash::extract($visits, '{n}.Visit.job_id');

    // pass the job id's to the conditions for the jobs
    $conditions['Job.id'] = $visit_jobs_ids;

    // get all subcontractor jobs
    $subcontractor_jobs = $this->Job->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));
    $subcontractor_job_count = array();

    foreach ($subcontractors as $key => $value) {

       // this is where I am getting stuck
       $subcontractor_job_count[$value['Supplier.name']] = ));
    }
```

I am sort of half way there, just struggling to get a count of how many jobs raised per subcontractor, any ideas?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you'd try to solve this on SQL level? I mean, that's what relational databases are good for, right? Also what about **[counter cache](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count)**?

Comment: Well the whole point of ORM is so that it takes away the complexity of writing manual joins and complex queries, in all fairness Cake has a great data abstraction layer to work with so I see no point of doing these queries in native SQL.

Comment: I'm not saying that you should create SQL manually, the ORM is capable of building joins via an "abstract interface" too (even though it's not nearly as nice in 2.x as it is in 3.x). **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables**